# No valid credential source for S3 backend found with GitHub OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, github-actions, openid-connect

I am working with Github OIDC to login to AWS and Deploy our terraform code, I am stuck on terraform init, most of the solutions on the internet point towards deleting the credentials file or providing the credentials explicitly, I can't do any of those since the credentials file does not exist with OIDC and I don't want to explicitly provide the Access_key and Secret_ID explicitly in the backend moduel either since that could lead to a security risk, Here's my GitHub Deployment file:

```
name: AWS Terraform Plan & Deploy

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - "infrastructure/**"
    # branches-ignore:
    #   - '**'
  pull_request:

env:
  tf_actions_working_dir: infrastructure/env/dev-slb-alpha/dev
  tf_actions_working_dir_prod: infrastructure/env/prod-slb-prod/prod
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  TF_WORKSPACE: "default"
  TF_ACTION_COMMENT: 1
  plan: "plan.tfplan"
  BUCKET_NAME : "slb-dev-terraform-state"
  AWS_REGION : "us-east-1"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - run: sleep 5 # there's still a race condition for now
      - name: Clone Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
         aws-region: us-east-1
         role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::262267462662:role/slb-dev-github-actions-role
         role-session-name: GithubActionsSession

      # - name: Configure AWS
      #   run: |
      #     export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::262267462662:role/slb-dev-github-actions-role
      #     # export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/tmp/awscreds
      #     export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

      #     # echo AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE >> $GITHUB_ENV
      #     echo AWS_ROLE_ARN=$AWS_ROLE_ARN >> $GITHUB_ENV
      #     echo AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - run: aws sts get-caller-identity

  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: Dev
      url: https://dev.test.com
    name: checkov-action-dev
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          submodules: 'true'
#       - name: Add Space to Dev
#         run: |
#           sysconfig -r proc exec_disable_arg_limit=1
#         shell: bash

      - name: Run Checkov action
        run: |
          pip3 install checkov
          checkov --directory /infrastructure
        id: checkov
#         uses: bridgecrewio/checkov-action@master
#         with:
#          directory: infrastructure/
         #skip_check: CKV_AWS_1
#          quiet: true
#          soft_fail: true
         #framework: terraform

  tfsec:
    name: tfsec
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # - name: Terraform security scan
      #   uses: aquasecurity/tfsec-pr-commenter-action@v0.1.10
      #   env:
      #     GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: tfsec
        uses: tfsec/tfsec-sarif-action@master
        with:
          # sarif_file: tfsec.sarif
          github_token: ${{ secrets.INPUT_GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # - name: Upload SARIF file
      #   uses: github/codeql-action/upload-sarif@v1
      #   with:
      #     sarif_file: tfsec.sarif

  superlinter:
    name: superlinter
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Scan Code Base
        # uses: github/super-linter@v4
        # env:
        #   VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false
        #   # DEFAULT_BRANCH: master
        #   GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        #   VALIDATE_TERRAFORM_TERRASCAN: false
        uses: terraform-linters/setup-tflint@v1
        with:
          tflint_version: v0.29.0

  terrascan:
    name: terrascan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run Terrascan
        id: terrascan
        uses: accurics/terrascan-action@v1
        with:
          iac_type: "terraform"
          iac_version: "v15"
          policy_type: "aws"
          only_warn: true
          #iac_dir:
          #policy_path:
          #skip_rules:
          #config_path:

  terraform:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.tf_actions_working_dir}}

    name: "Terraform"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Clone Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''
      - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.1.2

      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: |
          # # cat ~/.aws/crendentials
          # # export AWS_PROFILE=pki-aws-informatics
          # aws configure list-profiles
          #terraform init -backend-config="bucket=slb-dev-terraform-state"
          terraform init -backend-config="access_key=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}" -backend-config="secret_key=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}"
          terraform init --backend-config="access_key=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}" --backend-config="secret_key=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}"

      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate -no-color

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: terraform plan -var-file="terraform.tfvars" -out=${{ env.plan }}

      - uses: actions/github-script@0.9.0
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          PLAN: "terraform\n${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}"
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.INPUT_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const output = `#### Terraform Format and Style \`${{ steps.fmt.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Initialization ⚙️\`${{ steps.init.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Validation ${{ steps.validate.outputs.stdout }}
            #### Terraform Plan \`${{ steps.plan.outcome }}\`

            <details><summary>Show Plan</summary>

            \`\`\`${process.env.PLAN}\`\`\`

            </details>

            *Pusher: @${{ github.actor }}, Action: \`${{ github.event_name }}\`, Working Directory: \`${{ env.tf_actions_working_dir }}\`, Workflow: \`${{ github.workflow }}\`*`;

            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: output
            })
```

As you can see I have tried it a couple of ways and still end up with the same error, which is  [image: this], I have made sure that the profile we using is correct,I also cannot proivde credentials in the init command itself,it is validating to the correct profile since it is fetching the correct arn for the profile I need it to work on, I also read somewhere that the credentials for aws profiles and S3 could be different and if that is the case how can I integrate OIDC in ythat project, not sure what or where I might be going wrong otherwise, appreciate any help or headers,

Comment: My guess is that this is related to the Terraform AWS provider version 4. Can you verify in the log file that is the version that got installed?

Comment: Yeah, that is the version installed, do you think that could be the issue though? because it seems like an authentication issue.

Comment: As far as I am aware, some parts related to authentication have been dropped in AWS SDK for Go v2. I have seen a lot of similar questions these past three days related to broken authentication. I suggest pinning the version in required_providers block to `~> 3.0` until you have some time to figure things out. Because 4.0 brought a lot of breaking changes.

Comment: We are on version 3.51.0, and still the same error.

Comment: @tryna have you solved this?

Comment: I doubt this is related to the Terraform AWS provider itself - the error that you have is related to the Terraform S3 backend itself (which is part of Terraform Core rather than the AWS provider). Still need to figure out how to make it work though!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give advice specific to Github (since I'm using Bitbucket), but if you're using OIDC for access to AWS from your SCM of choice the same principals apply. The S3 backend for Terraform itself doesn't allow specifying any of the normal configuration for OIDC, but you can set this with environment variables and have it work:

- `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=<web-identity-token-file>`
- `AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/<role-name>`

For Bitbucket Pipelines users:

- Specify `oidc: true` in your pipelines config
- Write the OIDC token file using e.g. `echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token`
- Export the environment variables as above

I've split my S3 backend storage away from the account that has resources, so will need to look at configuring the actual AWS provider separately - it does have options for `assume_role.web_identity_token_file` and `assume_role.role_arn`